# Not able to convert Spark dataframe to Pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe Df with around 130 000 rows, 5000 customer ids & 7000 product ids. I am generating all possible customer id & product id combinations (34 million rows) using cross join & storing it in fullouter. I am removing combinations from fullouter that are already present in Df & then finding allPredictions using my model.

So far so good. But I want to convert allPredictions (30 million rows) to a pandas dataframe. I understand that the conversion is going to be difficult via `toPandas()` because of no of rows. So what I did is I took only top 1 prediction for each customer id - did this using windows function & row number function.

I assume that allPredictions size should have reduced considerably to 5000 customers * 1 prediction per customer = 5000 rows. I "assume" because `count()` also takes too long to return the number of rows. `toPandas()` should work on the topPredictions dataframe right. But it isn't working. Taking too long >40 mins & since i am working in google colab, the session goes inactive after some time.

I am new to Spark. Am I doing something wrong here? What changes should I make in my code? Also, i tried writing it as parquet - takes too long. i tried write.csv too - same problem.

```
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("trial")
conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled",'true')
conf.set("spark.rpc.message.maxSize",'1024mb')
conf.set("spark.executor.memory", '8g')
conf.set('spark.executor.cores', '8')
conf.set('spark.cores.max', '8')
conf.set("spark.driver.memory", '45g')
conf.set('spark.driver.maxResultSize', '21G')
conf.set("spark.driver.bindAddress", '127.0.0.1')
conf.set("spark.worker.cleanup.enabled",True)
conf.set("spark.executor.heartbeatInterval", "200000")
conf.set("spark.network.timeout", "300000")
self.sparkContext = SparkContext().getOrCreate(conf=conf)
self.sparkContext.setCheckpointDir('/checkpoint')
best_als = ALS(rank=10, maxIter=20, regParam=1.0,alpha=200.0, userCol="customerId",itemCol="productId",ratingCol="purch",implicitPrefs=True)

model=best_als.fit(Df)

df1 = Df.select("customerId")
df2 = Df.select("productId")

fullouter = df1.crossJoin(df2)

bigtest=fullouter.join(data, ["customerId","productId"],"left_anti")

allPredictions=model.transform(bigtest)

from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import rank, col, row_number

window = Window.partitionBy(allPredictions['customerId']).orderBy(allPredictions['prediction'].desc())

top_allPredictions=allPredictions.select('*', row_number().over(window).alias('rank')).filter(col('rank') <= 1)

dataframe=top_allPredictions.toPandas()
```

Comment: In order to do the window function, Spark needs to generate all 34 million rows (even if it doesn't need to return all of them to Pandas it still needs to compute them).  I suspect that the computing resources available in Google collab are just not enough to do this - you need a proper Spark cluster.

Comment: @RobinL Yes. I fixed this by writing each variable's result as csv & rereading the csvs again. This worked. I finally converted top_allPredictions to pandas. But, there should be some other efficient way right? Can caching all  the RDDs help here?

Comment: My guess is that caching/persisting would not help - in fact caching to memory might make the problem worse.  Since you have limited computing resources, the only way a large calculation is likely to be successful is if you split it into enough tasks (partitions) that each can compute individually without needing to hold all the data in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
from pyspark.sql import *  
from pyspark.sql.functions import *  
from pyspark.sql.types import *  
import numpy as np    
import pandas as pd


dataframe= top_allPredictions.select("*").toPandas()
```